# Сохранение данных в размещенной в IIS WCF-службе

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

Я разместил в IIS WCF-службу, и при работе, при вызове её методов я хочу, чтобы которые данные записывались в текстовый файл. 
Как в размещенной WCF указать путь на ПК, куда стоит создавать и сохранять текстовый файл?

Comment: Добавьте в конфигурационный файл WCF путь к файлу, в который вы собираетесь писать. Далее из конфига читаете путь файлу, и пишите в него.

Comment: @sp7, конфигурационный файл WCF - это Web.config?

Comment: Да, в секции `appSettings` объявляете нужный ключ, в котором значением будет путь к файлу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `Web.config` в разделе `configuration` в секции `appSettings` добавляете ключ и значение для него следующим образом:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>         
      <!-- Путь к файлу -->
      <add key="myFile" value="C:\myFile.txt" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Далее в коде, используя класс `ConfigurationManager` обращаетесь по ключу и читаете значение:

```
var filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myFile"]; // вернет C:\myFile.txt
```

P.S. Для того что бы класс `ConfigurationManager` был доступен, необходимо подключить библиотеку `System.Configuration.dll`